# Unity Auth Error With Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine

I implemented Firebase into a Unity app I am creating. There are two buttons that will run the two functions to create a new user and login an existing user. So far this functionality works on my PC, however whenever I try to deploy it to my android phone or Mac I end up getting the following error in the console.

```
DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.1.0
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor ()
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for SWIGExceptionHelper
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE..cctor ()
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE
Firebase.AppUtil.SetLogFunction (Firebase.LogMessageDelegate arg0)
```

It appears there is a missing .dll file, however I cannot for the life of me find out how to include it within the project file. I also have double checked the package name and it is the exact same name as the one made for my Firebase project, the google-services JSON in the root of the project, and the Api compatibility level is set to .NET 2.0. On top of that I also uninstalled and reinstalled the app a few times. I also tried using the Play Services Resolver which didn't help much at all either.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error here, only with Firebase Cloud Messaging. After tinkering around in a fashion similar to yours I concluded that it was caused by corruption during import of Firebase Package.

What worked for me:

- Deleted each and every folder created while importing Firebase Package.

[image]

- Reimported Firebase Package